# Iterate through Power BI report names from PBI app with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, powerbi

I have a Power BI app comprised of several Power BI reports, and I'd like to iterate through the reports (and subpages if possible) to take a screenshot of each with a Python script. I've built everything but this part because I can't seem to find where the Power BI web service html contains the report names. I'm familiar with using the chrome webdriver, selenium, beautiful soup (e.g.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = r'C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe'
s = Service(path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get('https://.....')
driver.maximize_window()
sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "email").send_keys('my email') 
#this is to login to the PBI web service on the chrome driver
reports = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '...') 
# ^ this is what I'm looking for help on - where in the html does PBI store report names?
```

but just can't find where in the html the report names are. I suspect it's in one of PowerBI's hidden javascript portions and maybe not possible.

Is this idea possible? Thank you in advance.

I've tried searching the html for the report names but can't find it.

Comment: Please read [ask] and make sure to provide a [mre].

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't share much reproducible code since the question is more focused on where in the Power BI app source code might the report titles be. The app is confidential as well. I'll add something to the original post.